# Trying to add radius to google places Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, google-places-api

In the app I am currently working on, a user can create an event.  When a user goes to type in the location of the event, we are auto completing the form field and filling it with the Google Places API.  Right now, I have the following Coffeescript code which I do not understand very well:

```
initLocationField = ->
      addListing.locationField.autocomplete
        messages:
          noResults: '',
          results: ->
        source: (request, response) ->
          $.ajax
            url: "/locations"
            data:
              term: request.term
              size_type: "local"
              include_google_places: true
            success: (data) ->
              response data
```

According to Google's autocomplete documentation, there are two optional parameters I should be interested in; location (latitude and longitude of a user, which we already have), and radius (distance in meters we would like the user to be able to search by).

I do not know where these optional parameter can be added to this Coffeescript code.  Maybe somewhere under data?

I already know that the parameters I am looking to pass in are:

```
location: current_user.coords
radius: 30000
```

Just don't know where to put those in here.

****UPDATE

After adding in the parameter

```
radius: 30000
```

to the data: set in the Coffeescript code, I have found some new things.  Going to my terminal I now see the following happening when I type in text to the text field:

```
Started GET "/locations?term=1&size_type=local&include_google_places=true&radius=30000" 

    for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-24 10:25:00 -0500
Processing by TagsController#locations as */*
  Parameters: {"term"=>"1", "size_type"=>"local", "include_google_places"=>"true", "radius"=>"30000"}
```

Since it's telling me this is being processed by the TagsController#locations here is that action:

```
  def locations
    @results = Location.autocomplete(location_params(params))
    respond_with(@results)
  end
```

So it looks like some of these data attributes are being passed into the url similar to the way the google documents show it.  Could this be working is a similar fashion?

Also the first individual that responded to my question (thank you) mentioned that the actual code for google places might be going on elsewhere, where could that be?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are not calling google Places API with this code. It seems like calling some local URI of your application with custom parameters ("term", "size_type" and "include_google_places") that are not used in Places API call to autocomplete.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Anyway if adding two additional parameters is what you strive for you can add this by adding

```
location: current_user.coords
radius: 30000
```

just below data: element

Comment: Are these parameters going to be associated with the google places?  See my edits above.

Comment: look like those parameters are used to create location_params object and then Ruby method Location.autocomplete is called .. my guess is that it will be the place where processing is done.